# Python3: another user doesn't see the library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 windows system users:

- user1
- user2

When running in Python3 the script:

```
import pandas
```

Module is imported successfully - under user1

Module is not found - under user2

Location of the library is

```
pandas.__file__
>>> 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py'
```

How to make the user2 to see pandas library?
It is possible to install library from user2. But pandas - is not the only library and it will take much time.

I've heard something about environment path, but didn't work with this.
Would you advise me the first steps to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you install pandas?

Comment: ```'C:\\Users\\user1\\...``` it seems pandas is only installed in user1. Try to pip install it for user2.

Comment: Daweo, I installed pandas by running under user1: python -m pip install lib_name.whl

Comment: Jobo Fernandez, thank you. It will certainly help. But I'm not sure, it's the rational way. If user3 appear, I will be to install the library again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a [virtual environment](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-setup-a-python-virtual-environment-on-windows-10/), and then just call env/scripts/activate.bat

install your librarys

then call your python script in there.